# How to fix unwanted HTML code in generated documentation?

Tags: m2doc

M2DOC on Capella 1.3.0. I have unwanted HTML code in my generated .DOCX file.

I have created a model starting from the tutorial, but when applied, in the resulting docx file, all the object descriptions have HTML tags that are not corrctly translated in the docx file, and visualized as they are.

Is there any way to tell the model to interprete HTML code and translate it in the .docx?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a release date for this feature. The [PoC](https://github.com/ylussaud/M2Doc/commit/996733cb4fbb5e8ab874f00032d8ed99512d1606) we have so far need the input to be xhtml not broken html. This make it hard to use when you don't control the input html.

Comment: This is more a bug than a feature, Capella automatically converts comments in HTML to maintain text formats. I can't control html autogenerated code but I described all the objects in my project in theese descriptions (a very complex project), so I need them in my docs without HTML tags around them. To correct the problem, I have to copy/past all the description in a plain HTML file, open it with a browser, and then re-copy/past from the browser to the docx. If you download the exemple project from http://www.m2doc.org/capella/ you will obtain the same bug in the generated documentation